# MiniMagick image permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, minimagick

I am using MiniMagick wrapper for ImageMagick

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open(product.deal_image_url)
image = resize_with_crop(image, 150, 100)
image.format "jpg"
image.write "public/images/products/image"+product.id.to_s+".jpg"
```

Now this image is saved with permissions 0600 ... I want to store it with 0644
can I use something like

```
image.permissions 0644
```

Answer (score 0):

No, Imagemagick's MiniMagick would not handle file-system permissions. You can do something like...

```rb
File.chmod(0644, "public/images/products/image"+product.id.to_s+".jpg")
```